# Django: Proxy Meta-class ignoring verbose_name_plural

Tags: python, django, django-admin, reverse-engineering

Django-admin is pluralizing a model that I have running as a proxy class.

The normal case here works fine:

```
class Triviatheme(models.Model):
    [  ... elided ... ]
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'TriviaTheme'
        verbose_name_plural='trivia themes'
```

But for a main content table, I have a parent model called 'Content', and a proxy class:

```
class News(Content):
    DTYPE='News'
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='News'
        proxy = True
```

But with the Meta in Content is still pluralizing 'News' resulting in 'Newss', so its ignoring the verbose_name_plural field, but not the proxy field.

Similarly, overriding the field in the parent class seems to have no effect. What am I missing? Is there a better way of implementing a large table model with a discriminator column?

Note that this is reverse engineering a DB from a different app, so the model is pretty well set and I can't just change the schema.

*edit*:

I'm on python 2.6 / Django 1.2.1

I'm also using a Manager class to handle the discriminator, but its still not working.

Comment: What version of Python/Django are you using?  On Python 2.6/Django 1.2.1, I tried your example and it works fine as far as I can tell:  Content becomes Contents and News remains News when pluralized.

Comment: What does the 'Content' class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW I tested this with Django 1.1.1 and Django 1.2.1 and it worked as expected in both cases.

Comment: I redid this from scratch and it started working, so it was probably some screwy configuration.